# Setting up SPF record for A2Hosting shared hosting

Tags: email, spam, spf, dkim

I'm trying to setup A2Hosting SPF correctly since the proposed SPF is landing the emails in the SPAM folder in Gmail.

This is the default SPF: `v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:210.125.99.77 ~all`

But when checking the deliverability in https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability I see that the SPF is missing something, since the SPF bit is flagged as incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

After some intensive research all over the internet here my solution:

You need to include the following bit in your SPF definition:

```
include:relay.mailchannels.net
```

Otherwise mails are flagged as spam:

Complete SPF record:

```
v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:210.125.99.77 include:relay.mailchannels.net include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

A great tool that helped a lot during the whole process: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx